# wxWidgets - width of wxListbook list

Tags: c++, list, user-interface, width, wxwidgets

I have a wxListbook set up and I want to set a static width for the left list in which the page titles are shown. Currently, when no pages are added, it does not have any width and when pages are added, the width becomes whatever the longest title spacing is.

Empty: [image]

Added pages: [image]

I have tried several things, but have had no luck.

First, I tried setting a column width, but didn't see any difference:

```
listBook = new wxListbook( this, ID_LISTBOOK, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxLB_LEFT );

wxListView* listBookListView1 = listBook->GetListView();
listBookListView1->SetColumnWidth(0,400); //tried 0,1,-1 for the first parameter
```

Then, I tried SetMinSize, but again, no difference:

```
listBook = new wxListbook( this, ID_LISTBOOK, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxLB_LEFT );
    listBook->SetMinSize(wxSize(400,500));
```

I also tried SetSize, but no difference:

```
listBook = new wxListbook( this, ID_LISTBOOK, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxLB_LEFT );
listBook->SetSize(wxSize(200,200));
```

What would be the correct way to do this? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `wxListbook` always fits the list to its contents. Personally I really wonder why should this be a problem, in particular why would you want to have a `wxListbook` without any pages and what could it be useful for. But, in principle, setting the minimal size of the list control should work and if you can change wxWidgets to do it like this, we'd gladly apply a [patch](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/wiki/HowToSubmitPatches) doing it.

However right now there is no way to do this, sorry.

Comment: Could you please refer to what file I'd have to change?

I've tried "SetMinSize", "SetColumnWidth" and whatnot and it seems like when I create a wxListview, it's a subclass. By all accounts, it should work, but isn't.

Comment: You'd need to change the implementation of `wxBookCtrlBase` probably, i.e. the file `src/common/bookctrl.cpp` in wxWidgets itself.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the similar issue with wxTreebook, even prepared the patch for this but it was rejected because potentially breaks functionality of custom book controls.
By default all custom book controls have strange behavour related to layout of inner selector control (wxListView, wxTreeCtrl etc.)
If you want, I can try to find that code of wxTreebook and send it to you. Maybe you will find there something useful.

Possible solutions which you could try to fix that:

- Add the fake item which contains several spaces to the listbook, then show the frame, then remove that item (quick and dirty but I'm almost sure that will work and list view will have a non-zero width)
- Patch the source code of wxListbook by yourself (wxWidgets is open-source and you can easily modify the source code, then create the patch and re-use it after upgrading to new version of wxWidgets)
- Try to change the MinSize of inner wxListView after displaying the frame and calling Layout()

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your third point? And it would be great if you could post some of your code, thanks.

Comment: Also, the first point would not work. It does automatic resizing.