# Increase width of the ListCtrl within a wx.Listbook

Tags: wxpython

I'm using a `wx.Listbook`, which uses a ListCtrl to select pages within the Listbook. However, the width of the ListCtrl is less than the shortest page name. I would like to increase the width so that the page names are not truncated, but can't seem to.

Of course, I can access the ListCtrl using `Listbook.GetListView()`. However, changing the size has no effect. I also tried to access the sizer of the ListCtrl (via `myListCtr.GetContainingSizer()`) but that returns `None`.

How can I increase the width of the ListCtrl within a wx.Listbook?

```py
import wx

class MyApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Example")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.myListBook = wx.Listbook(panel, style=wx.LB_LEFT)

        # Access listCtr
        myListCtr = self.myListBook.GetListView()

        # Failed attempt to resize sizer
        # lcSizer = myListCtr.GetContainingSizer()
        # lcSizer.SetItemMinSize(myListCtr, 500, -1)

        # Second failed attempt
        # sizeritem = lcSizer.GetItem(self.myListCtr)
        # sizeritem.SetProportion(1)
        # sizeritem.SetMinSize(500, -1)

        # Resize ListCtr has to effect
        self.myListCtr.SetSize(500, -1)

        # Add a (blank) page with a long name
        page = wx.Panel(self.myListBook)
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page, "A Long Page Title")

        sizer.Add(self.myListBook, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetAutoLayout(True)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(panel)
        sizer.SetSizeHints(panel)
        panel.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyApp()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: Screenshot of ListBook with ListCtr which is too narrow]

I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.8.1, and wxPython 4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `SetColumnWidth` on the `ListCtrl` after all pages have been added. This will cause the column width and by extension the total width of the ListCtrl to be recalculated.

```py
myListCtrl = self.myListBook.GetListView()
myListCtrl.SetColumnWidth(0, -1)
```

We could set the column width to a hard value, but by using `-1` we tell it to calculate the width by using the width of the longest item in the list. Therefore, the call needs to be made after the last page is added.

Here is a complete example:

```py
import wx

class MyApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Example")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.myListBook = wx.Listbook(panel, size=(500, 500), style=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT)

        page1 = wx.Panel(self.myListBook)
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page1, "A Long Page Title")

        page2 = wx.Panel(self.myListBook, -1)
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page2, "An Even Longer Page Title")

        page3 = wx.Panel(self.myListBook, -1)
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page3, "Page 3")

        # Access listCtr and calculate column width
        myListCtrl = self.myListBook.GetListView()
        myListCtrl.SetColumnWidth(0, -1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myListBook, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        panel.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyApp()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And here is what that looks like on Windows:

[image: screenshot]

Note that autocalculating may not work as desired in every application. In the example application above, the ListBook is not drawn until after the last page is added and the column width is recalculated. However, in the real application I encountered this issue with, the ListBook is initially drawn/rendered to the screen empty and then pages are added/removed through normal use of the application. In that case, the ListCtrl is not resized after a page is added and `SetColumnWidth` is called, only the column is resized. If the column grows to be bigger than the ListCtrl, then a scrollbar appears allowing the user to scroll to view the cutoff ends of the items. However, if the column shrinks, then the right column border is pulled in to the end of the longest item. While I could have made a call to redraw the ListBook, that would make the contents of the pages move left/right each time. Instead, I simply set the column width to a hard value once at app launch. I just chose a value which worked in most cases for the context of that app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `sizer` for each page added.

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Example")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.myListBook = wx.Listbook(panel, -1, style=wx.LIST_FORMAT_LEFT)

        page1 = wx.Panel(self.myListBook, -1)
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page1, "A really............. Long Page Title")

        page1_stuff = wx.StaticText(page1, wx.ID_ANY, ("Items in the page 1"))
        page1_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        page1_sizer.Add(page1_stuff, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        page1.SetSizer(page1_sizer)

        page2 = wx.Panel(self.myListBook, -1)
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page2, "Page 2")

        page2_stuff = wx.StaticText(page2, wx.ID_ANY, ("Items in the page 2"))
        page2_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        page2_sizer.Add(page2_stuff, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        page2.SetSizer(page2_sizer)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myListBook, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyApp()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

> [Responding to your comments - 2nd Attempt]

I'm struggling to `make` this go wrong.
Even resorting to dropping the sizers and fixing the `Listbook` size continues to arrange the items proportionally.

```
import wx

class MyApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Example", size=(1000,700))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.myListBook = wx.Listbook(panel, -1, size=(350, 500))

        page = wx.Panel(self.myListBook)
        page.SetBackgroundColour('yellow')
        page_stuff = wx.StaticText(page, wx.ID_ANY, ("Item in the page 1"))
        page2 = wx.Panel(self.myListBook)
        page2.SetBackgroundColour('lightblue')
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page, "A Long Page Title ...............X")
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page2, "Another Long Page Title")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyApp()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: That has not effect. I just tried your example, and the behavior is exactly the same at mine. Although, based on the style of your screenshot, it appears you are not on Windows. I am. Could that make a difference?

Comment: @Waylan Given that you ran the same code, I suppose it must make a difference, although I can not test that. I should point out that I'm running wxpython `4.1.1 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5`, if you are running a previous version, that may matter too.

Comment: I'm running wxPython `4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5`. It appears that the only difference between us is the OS. That's frustrating.

Comment: And yes, I ran your code exactly verbatim as-is.

Comment: @Waylan See my 2nd attempt

Comment: Your second attempt makes no difference. For me, the ListCtrl always has a width of 80.

Comment: @Waylan my gut feeling, is that there is an issue, on Windows, with the `wxwidget`. Start digging here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634986/wxwidgets-width-of-wxlistbook-list

Comment: I figured it out. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71429136/866026). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. See my note on *lb_width*

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Wx App'

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # This width affects the width of the lstctrl
        lb_width = 600
        self.myListBook = wx.Listbook(self, style=wx.LB_LEFT, size=(lb_width, 600))

        # Access listCtr
        page = wx.Panel(self.myListBook)
        self.myListBook.AddPage(page, "A Long Page Title. As long as you like")
        myListCtr = self.myListBook.GetListView()
        myListCtr.Size = (400, 500)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.myListBook)
        self.Layout()
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It has no effect whatsoever.